# Remove duplicates from a dataframe based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a `df` with columns - `name`,`cost` and `status`.

```
            name        cost      status
    0       alex        5          pass
    1       alex        6          pass
    2       alex        7          pass
    3       marcus      23         pass
    4       marcus      78         fail
    5       anthony     1          pass
    6       paul        89         pass
    7       paul        23         pass
    8       paul        10         fail
    9       paul         8         pass
```

if one of the `name` column record has `status = fail`. I'm trying to removing whole user's record.

```
            name        cost      status
    0       alex        5          pass
    1       alex        6          pass
    2       alex        7          pass
    3       anthony     1          pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for compare if not equal value `fail` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for test if all `True`s per groups by [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['status'].ne('fail').groupby(df['name']).transform('all')]
print (df)
      name  cost status
0     alex     5   pass
1     alex     6   pass
2     alex     7   pass
5  anthony     1   pass
```

Or get all names where `status` equal `fail` and filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `~` for inverse mask for all names with no such names:

```
df = df[~df['name'].isin(df.loc[df['status'].eq('fail'), 'name'])]
print (df)
      name  cost status
0     alex     5   pass
1     alex     6   pass
2     alex     7   pass
5  anthony     1   pass
```